# Push index values of one array that only match keys of an object

Tags: arrays

I have an object:

> PiecePrize = {0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c", 3:"d", 4:"e"}

and an array:

> myPieces = [1, 3, 7, 56];

I only want to push values of myPieces to the collection id if they are also in the PiecePrize object.

So, trying to loop through each index of myPieces and if there is a match with a key in the PiecePrize object, then push it along with value pair as a new list element.

I can get it to work without the if statement part, but as soon as I try to add that in it doesn't work and I'm not getting any errors.

```
function opCollection() {
  var newHTML = [];
  $.each(myPieces, function(index, value) {
    if(jQuery.inArray(value, PiecePrize) >= 0) {
      newHTML.push('<li>' + value + ": " + PiecePrize[value] + '</li>');
    }
  });
  $("#collection").html(newHTML.join(""));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PiecePrize is not an array.

So,

```
if(jQuery.inArray(value, PiecePrize) >= 0)
```

should be

```
if( PiecePrize[value] )
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. New to coding, so was making it more complicated than it needed to be.